# How to add pictures to Powerpoint Presentation Picture PlaceHolder?

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have created some code in Excel VBA to create a PowerPoint presentation 1 slide for each row of Excel, and populate in a specific text box in PowerPoint.
I now want to add in all the images that match the description. These are all Jpegs and not charts etc.
How can I do this, and is it better to do this in excel, or is it better to do this Powerpoint VBA itself?
Eitherway, would anyone be able to help me out with some code on how to do this please?
The image frames already exist in PowerPoint. There are 2 images per slide (no transitions or anything).
Thank you!

P.S I am using PowerPoint and Excel 2010 on Windows 7.

---

Is there a way to do this from Excel? The rest of my code is in Excel and It would be great to do that as part of the Macro.
Basically I have a file location that I want to use e.g. C:\insertfoldername\imagename.jpeg appears in column H in the spreadsheet (about 400 rows).
The Powepoint template I am using has the image frame (The one in Powerpoint, that wehn you hover over it says.."Insert Picture from file".
These are already sized and are in the right location.
What I want to do is, in Excel, Paste the image from the file path that is in excel and past it into that specific Image frame.
Is that going to be possible at all?

Basically something that will do this:
`PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(3)LoadImage(spath)`

Below is the code I am using.
**** Indicates the File path. the jpg file is set as the 3rd column in the excel spreadsheet.

```
Sub CreateSlides()
'Dim the Excel objects
Dim objWorkbook As New Excel.Workbook
Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

'Dim the File Path String
Dim strFilePath As String

'Dim the PowerPoint objects
Dim PPT As Object
Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim pptLayout As PowerPoint.CustomLayout
Dim pptNewSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim str As String
Dim Title As String

Set PPT = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

PPT.Visible = True

'Get the layout of the first slide and set a CustomLayout object
Set pptLayout = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout

'Run the OpenFile function to get an Open File dialog box. It returns a String containing the file and path.
strFilePath = OpenFile()

'Open the Excel file
Set objWorkbook = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open(strFilePath)

'Grab the first Worksheet in the Workbook
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

'Loop through each used row in Column A
For i = 2 To objWorksheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

Set PPT = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

Set pptNewSlide = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, pptLayout)

 'Get the number of columns in use on the current row
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim boldWords As String

    boldWords = "Line1: ,line2: ,Line3: ,Line4: "
    LastCol = objWorksheet.Rows(i).End(xlToRight).Column
    If LastCol = 16384 Then LastCol = 1 'For some reason if only column 1 has data it returns 16384, so correct it

    'Build a string of all the columns on the row
    str = ""
    str = "Line1: " & str & objWorksheet.Cells(i, 1).Value & Chr(13) & _
    "Line2: " & objWorksheet.Cells(i, 2).Value & Chr(13) & _
    "Line3: " & objWorksheet.Cells(i, 10).Value & Chr(13) & _
    "Line4: " & objWorksheet.Cells(i, 7).Value & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & _
    objWorksheet.Cells(i, 14).Value

 sfile = Cells(i, 3) & ".jpg" **** This is the jpg name

Set PPT = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

spath = "C:\test\"

'Write the string to the slide
pptNewSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = objWorksheet.Cells(i, 3).Value 'This enters the film Title
PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = str


BoldSomeWords PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).Shapes(1), str, boldWords

'This is where I want to load in the Image.
'PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).Shapes(3).Picture = LoadPicture(spath) ' & sfile)
'PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(3)LoadImage((spath))

Next
End Sub
```

---

```
Function OpenFile()
'Dim the File Dialog object and string
Dim objFileDialog As FileDialog
Dim strFile As String

'Set the objFileDialog to an instance of the FileDialog object
Set objFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

'Set the Properties of the objFileDialog object
objFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
objFileDialog.ButtonName = "Select"
objFileDialog.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
objFileDialog.Title = "Select Excel File"
objFileDialog.InitialFileName = "C:\"
objFileDialog.Filters.Clear
objFileDialog.Filters.Add "Excel", "*.xls; *.xlsx", 1
objFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1

'Show the FileDialog box
objFileDialog.Show

'Set strFile to the first record of the SelectedItems property of our FileDialog
strFile = objFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)

'Return the File Path string
OpenFile = strFile
End Function
```

Comment: `How can I do this, and is it better to do this in excel, or is it better to do this Powerpoint VBA itself?` In your case it is both. Since you get information from `Excel`. However, you need to know how to code adding those images in `PowerPoint`. So at the end, you'll bind `PowerPoint` to `Excel` which is what I suggest better. [HERE](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/168649) shows how to add images on `PowerPoint`.

Comment: By "image frames" do you mean picture or content placeholders?  You may not want to use these, since they'll compress your pictures for you and since they can crop/resize your pictures.  You can add pictures directly to the slide w/o using placeholders, then size them exactly as needed.  Whether to do the job from Excel or PPT depends as much as anything on where you/your users are most comfortable.  I write PPT add-ins, my customers use PPT, so when I wrote code to do pretty much exactly what you're describing, I did it as a PPT add-in that reads Excel files.

Comment: `What I want to do is, in Excel, Paste the image from the file path that is in excel and past it into that specific Image frame` Is this possible? YES. As I've commented, you need to know first how you'll program it in `PPT` and then you can use that command by binding `Excel` to `PPT`. Whether you use `Early` or `Late` binding is up to you.

Comment: Hi @L42, I want to know if it's possible to do FROM excel. You say 'know how to code adding those images in PowerPoint' That's the thing I need. I can do Strings easily 'using this code PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = str' It's Loading the image into the shape using the file path that I need. I don't know the code I need to use to do that. Thanks

Comment: Then start [HERE](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/XL_PPT.html). If you get stuck somewhere, get back here and post your code.

Comment: @L42 have added my code. The link Is very useful, however the image isn't stored in Excel, the jpg name is stored there. Thank you!

Comment: Try using the shapes `.Fill.UserPicture` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745495(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you add pictures in currently open PPT `Picture PlaceHolders` using Excel.
We used `Early Binding` adding the `Microsoft PowerPoint 14.0 Object Library` reference.

**Edit1:** Adding DoEvents and some explanation

```
Sub ImportPictureInPlaceHolderFromExcel()

    Dim oPPt As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim oPPtSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim oPPtShp As PowerPoint.Shape

    '~~> Get hold of PPt instance meaning your currently open PPT presentation
    Set oPPt = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
    '~~> Reference the first slide which should contain picture placeholders
    Set oPPtSlide = oPPt.ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

    '~~> Now check each shape in slide
    For Each oPPtShp In oPPtSlide.Shapes
        '~~> You only need to work on Picture place holders
        If oPPtShp.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderPicture Then
            With oPPtShp
                '~~> Now add the Picture
                '~~> For this example, picture path is in Cell A1
                oPPtSlide.Shapes.AddPicture Range("A1").Value, msoFalse, msoTrue, _
                                .Left, .Top, .Width, .Height
                '~~> Insert DoEvents here specially for big files, or network files
                '~~> DoEvents halts macro momentarily until the 
                '~~> system finishes what it's doing which is loading the picture file
                DoEvents
            End With
        End If
    Next

    Set oPPtSlide = Nothing
    Set oPPt = Nothing

End Sub
```

**To sum-up:**
1. We get hold of PPT application
2. We get hold of the slide and the shapes within the slide
3. Now we choose shapes which are `ppPlaceholderPicture` type only
4. We use the `Shape Object's`(ppPlaceholderPicture type) `.Top, .Left, .Width and .Height` property as argument for *Shapes Collection's* `.AddPicture` method.

And there you go, you've added a picture in your PPT Picture Placeholder.
Hope this is what you need.

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much @L42 exactly what I was after :).....If I put the images on a network drive, do I need to do anything special? It works fantastic on my C:\ but won't run over a network drive.

Comment: Ah that is due to network delay of course specially if the server is somewhere offsite or you are using wireless connection instead of LAN. Well you can try to add `DoEvents` after the `.AddPicture` statement and see if it works for you. If not, you will have to copy the pictures first in your local drive then run the macro. I think copy paste from drive to drive won't hurt so much. Cheers. Btw, see my edit for the `DoEvents`.

Answer (score 2):

While that **looks like** it works when you add an image to a slide with an empty picture or content placeholder it will always go into that placeholder and resize to fit.

You just need to add it like this:

```
osld.Shapes.AddPicture "Path", msoFalse, msoTrue, -1, -1
```