# How to add a picture to a powerpoint slide from excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have set up a macro which saves some charts from an Excel spreadsheet as pictures (as part of a larger procedure), and need some code to paste these pictures, one per slide, into a slideshow.

Currently, I have successfully opened up a powerpoint presentation with 4 blank slides, and have not even managed to successfully import 1 picture.

I have been using methods like shape.addpicture("C:\Users\restofpathname"), but have not managed to get them to work

Comment: Save the file name from excel then https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/168649 to Powerpoint?

Comment: Did you check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049917/how-to-add-pictures-to-powerpoint-presentation-picture-placeholder?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you both for the response <br/>
@HuangChen  - I have got to this code here  
`Dim oSlide As Slide  
Dim oPicture As Shape  
Dim applPP As PowerPoint.Application  
Dim prsntpp As PowerPoint.Presentation  

' Change slide index position to the first slide
Set applPP = New PowerPoint.Application
applPP.Visible = True
Set prsntpp = applPP.Presentations.Add
prsnpp.Select
ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide 1`

And I get an error "Compile Error, Invalid Qualifier", with "View" highlighted

Am unsure how to proceed?

Comment: Instead of modifying the question, you should add your solution to the thread as a response and mark it as resolved i.e. accept your own solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code which allowed me to put a picture in powerpoint, from excel. The code below works, and [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/168649) is also useful

```
Dim applPP As PowerPoint.Application, prsntPP As PowerPoint.Presentation, TitlePage As PowerPoint.Slide

    Set applPP = New PowerPoint.Application
    applPP.Visible = True
    Set prsntPP = applPP.Presentations.Add
    Set TitlePage = prsntPP.Slides.Add(Index:=1, Layout:=ppLayoutTitle)
    prsntPP.SaveAs ("C:\Users\...")

        Dim oSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
        Dim oPicture As PowerPoint.Shape

        Set oSlide = prsntPP.Slides(1)

        Set oPicture = oSlide.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Penguins.jpg", _
            msoFalse, msoTrue, 1, 2, 3, 4)

        oPicture.ScaleHeight 0.9, msoTrue
        oPicture.ScaleWidth 0.9, msoTrue

        With prsntPP.PageSetup
            oPicture.Left = (.SlideWidth \ 2) - (oPicture.Width \ 2)
            oPicture.Top = (.SlideHeight \ 2) - (oPicture.Height \ 2)
        End With
```